# Remote Desktop and Citrix both intermittently freezing / disconnecting/ reconnecting

Tags: remote-desktop, citrix

We are having an issue that arrives and then goes away by itself each day for the last week.

Users accessing via RDP (and this is via the RD Gateway to one of our multiple servers OR just directly connecting to a specific server via IP address), will get regular freezes or 'Reconnecting' messages which then load back up the session after 5-20 seconds.

It is not an Internet issue because it is happening from all our remote offices. The data center where the servers are located has a solid internet connection.

I've tried a lot of troubleshooting steps but I can't find any event viewer logs when this 'reconnecting' happens. I'm currently looking in Application and Service Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Terminalservices - Gateway > Operational' (This is on the gateway server).

I know the time when the users are getting 'reconnecting' but I can't find evidence of this in Event Viewer. I hope someone can help. Also, if they log in via Citrix they don't get this 'reconnecting' the screen just freezes.

Comment: At a minimum, pursuing this would require a correlated packet capture on an endpoint and the remote desktop host, filtered on the endpoint IP address.

Comment: You suspect the internet link, but I would even more suspect the server cpu%. A high load will cause the same symptom as you have. (If it's cpu related, make sure you test with user that are not targetted with a high load of GPO, as a bloated GPO can cause the user winlogon process to choke too)

Comment: yagmoth555 - sorry if I wasn't clear but I don't suspect it is the internet connection as the target internet is solid and there are various sources that the connections are coming from. Would you suspect the CPU on the individual server or on the connection broker (although this is affecting servers where we have gone in directly to the IP address too.

Comment: **"The target internet connection is solid"** is kind of a meaningless statement. Have you looked at it related to latency and packet loss? That's what I would suspect.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at latency and packet loss (this is just using a ping tool (pinginfoview), pinging every second). Is there a more accurate tool I could use?

Comment: Care to share your latency and packet loss findings with us?

Comment: @JohnCassell did you find a solution?  I have the same problem.  In my case I also believe it's neither the Internet connection, nor high CPU or memory utilization. The freeze is intermittent, lasts a few seconds, and when it comes back user clicks that got queued up are processed.  I'm using Citrix Workspace 22.10.0.21 and Windows 11 Pro on the client machine.